# How to restrict viewing promotion Record by subsidiary for employee

Tags: netsuite

I want to Restrict view/access to records based on a field value
We are on netsuite Oneworld and I would like to show only promotions create for a subsidiary

I don't know if it's possible, but I am thinking to create a custom field "subsidiary" on the promotion record to filter the access.
If the employee is from the same subsidiary than the promotion, he could see the record otherwise he won't

Maybe, there is a way with the Role permission (search, segment, ...) or directly with the record rule.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: So you are telling I have to exclude all possible solutions with SuiteScript ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the "Promotion" record in my environment so I could not test directly. But I did check the [Records Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2020_2/script/record/promotioncode.html) do not see "subsidiary" listed.  So I agree there is no built in mechanism specifically based on Subsidiary.  However there is "Location" listed and I know Locations are tied to specific subsidiaries.  Test to see if using "Location" would suffice.

Worse case, you can achieve this via scripting.  You can create a beforeLoad or pageInit function, use the runtime module to gather current user data, then evaluate where or not to redirect the user to a new page, display an alert, etc.

Comment: I thought about the location restriction but it will have other impacts so I had to remove this solution. I tried the second one, I created a custom field (subsidiary) and a workflow if the user.subsidiary != promotion.subsidiary it return an user error .  with this solution, the user can't access the record, but if he does a search with all information in the result he could see the record information.